# Error message when trying to connect to an Access database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I'm getting the following error message when trying to connect to my Access database:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Here is the code for my form:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Login

Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    'Change the following to your access database location
    dataFile = "C:\Users\115520963\Documents\users.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    'the query:
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("'SELECT * FROM [users] WHERE [username] = '" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND [password] = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'", myConnection)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    ' the following variable is hold true if user is found, and false if user is not found
    Dim userFound As Boolean = False
    ' the following variables will hold the user first and last name if found.
    Dim FirstName As String = ""
    Dim LastName As String = ""

    'if found:
    While dr.Read
        userFound = True
        FirstName = dr("FirstName").ToString
        LastName = dr("LastName").ToString
    End While

    'checking the result
    If userFound = True Then
        Secondary.Show()
        Secondary.lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " & FirstName & " " & LastName
    Else
        MsgBox("Sorry, username or password not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Login")
    End If

End Sub



End Class
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I do not understand why this error is occurring.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. You should call _myConnection.Open_ before trying to run ExecuteReader

Comment: Perfect it worked thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open the connection:

```
myConnection.Open
```

You may also want to wrap your code in a `Using` statement:

```
Using cmd As New OlbDbCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception message is telling you that you need an open connection so try:

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
myConnection.Open()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget myConnection.close when you are done.  Ideally, you should open as late as possible and close as soon as possible.